# I am trying all the selected arrays to change the style Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I can select more than one ID with the checkbox and they are all selected but only one of them is active in the css.
I want for each ID that I select to change the style .

This is my code.

```
 selectedAvailableValueItemIds: string[] = [];
  activeVI: '';

<div class="tab-item" fxLayout="row" [ngClass]="{active: activeVI === valueItem.id, 'tab-item': true}">
                      <div class="icon">
                          <app-checkbox [ngModel]="selectedAvailableValueItemIds.includes(valueItem.id)" (ngModelChange)="onSelectAvailableValueItem(valueItem)"></app-checkbox>
                        </div>
                    <div class="unAssignedVIs" [ngClass]="{active: activeVI === valueItem.id, 'unAssignedVIs': true}">
                        {{valueItem.name}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="ipUnAssignedVIs" [ngClass]="{active: activeVI === valueItem.id, 'ipUnAssignedVIs': true}">
                      {{Level[valueItem.level]}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

This is the TS

```
onSelectAvailableValueItem(valueItem: ValueItem) {
    const index = this.selectedAvailableValueItemIds.indexOf(valueItem.id);

    if (index < 0) {
      this.selectedAvailableValueItemIds.push(valueItem.id);
     this.activeVI = valueItem.id
    } else {
      this.selectedAvailableValueItemIds.splice(index, 1);
      this.activeVI = '';
    }
  }
```

This is the CSS

```
.unAssignedVIs {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  width: calc(100% - 34em);
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #ebebeb;
  &.active {
    background: white;

  }
}
```

Comment: do you forget ' ' in active? [ngClass]="{'active': activeVI === valueItem.id, 'tab-item': true}"

Comment: I didnt unserstand good ?

Comment: replace active by 'active': you missed the ' '

Comment: @Eliseo do you have any other idea while this is not working

Comment: I wrote an answer. Change the philosophy of your code, but I think is more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ZhuniquA. Sorry, I read too quickly your question. When we want to select one and only one element we have an unique variable, if we want to select one or more elements, generally add a new property to the element.

```
<!--I used a variable (really a property of valueItem) that I called checked -->
<div class="tab-item" fxLayout="row" [ngClass]="{'active': valueItem.checked, 'tab-item': true}">
     <div class="icon">
        <!--see that we can use as ngModel valueItem.checked-->
        <app-checkbox [(ngModel)]="valueItem.checked"></app-checkbox>
     </div>
     <div class="unAssignedVIs" [ngClass]="{'active': valueItem.checked, 'unAssignedVIs': true}">
        {{valueItem.name}}
     </div>
     <div class="ipUnAssignedVIs" [ngClass]="{'active': valueItem.checked, 'ipUnAssignedVIs': true}">
        {{Level[valueItem.level]}}
     </div>
</div>
```

The "magic" in this case is that we are using an object "valueItem", so we can add the property "checked" simply using valueItem.checked (If the property not exist is undefined)

Well, VisualStudio mark as "error" because we don't have the property "checked". Well. We can ignore this advertisment or, in code give the property

```
//If is an only element
   valueItem.checked=false;

//If we have an array of items we can write
//Imagine we have a variable items=[{name:"1",level:0},{name:"2",level:2},...]

this.items=this.items.map(item=>{
    return {...item,checked:false}
  })
```

Comment: Yeah but what will happen with the ngModelChange that is in the checkbox ?

Comment: At first is unchecked (the value is undefined), when check one time becomes true, if you uncheck it  becomes false. You can write {{valueItem|json}} to see the value

Comment: Would you help me to write the value ? 
because what did you write is to create a property checked with a type i dont know what and then to call here, have i good undersood

Comment: You needn't write any code (the .html make all the work), well, I updated my answer if you want to add a property "checked". Where the code goes? just when you get the value

Comment: I have another question before 2-3 days asked, can you show if you can help me on this ?