# How to collapse as accordion json object deatails that have *ngFor directive in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, ngfor

I want collapse and expand like accordion my json object details.I already used for loop and *ngFor directive.

```js
 toggleCollapse(){
    this.isCollapsed=!this.isCollapsed;
  }
```

```html
 <div class='wrapper' *ngFor="let t of response.articles">

        <div class='img-wrapper' *ngIf="isCollapsed">
            <img src='{{t.imgUrl}}' />
        </div>
        <div class='text-wrapper'>
            <h2>{{t.title}}</h2>
            <h5>{{t.description}}</h5>
            <div *ngIf="!isCollapsed ">
                <h5>{{t.content}}</h5>
            </div>
            <button *ngIf="isCollapsed" type="button" (click)="toggleCollapse()" class="btn btn-danger">Read more</button>
            <button *ngIf="!isCollapsed" (click)="toggleCollapse()" class="btn btn-danger">Read less</button>
        </div>
```

[image]

I write this code.When I click "Read More" button all the objects that I have expanding. 
I should need only expand clicked object only.how can I do this.?
thank you.

Comment: if you has more that one "div" to collapsed, you need more that one variable. Tipical you add to articles a variable and use t.iscollapsed, not collapsed see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045164/i-am-trying-all-the-selected-arrays-to-change-the-style-angular-4/51047338#51047338

Comment: Can you explain it please?I tried.but still I have the problem.

Comment: see my answer (and the comments)

Answer (score 0):

@Ruwan, the idea (no .ts)

```
 <div class='wrapper' *ngFor="let t of response.articles">
        <!--use t.isCollased, not only isCollapsed -->
        <div class='img-wrapper' *ngIf="t.isCollapsed">
            <img src='{{t.imgUrl}}' />
        </div>
        <div class='text-wrapper'>
            <h2>{{t.title}}</h2>
            <h5>{{t.description}}</h5>
            <div *ngIf="!t.isCollapsed ">
                <h5>{{t.content}}</h5>
            </div>
            <--in buttons we change directy the value of t.iscollapsed-->
            <button *ngIf="isCollapsed" type="button" (click)="t.isCollapsed=false" class="btn btn-danger">Read more</button>
            <button *ngIf="!isCollapsed" (click)="t.isCollapsed=true" class="btn btn-danger">Read less</button>
        </div>
```

See that the only I made is replace iscollapsed by t-isCollapsed. What is "t.collapsed"?. Well is a property of your objects response.articles.

Think that response.articles is like

```
[
  {imgUrl:"",title:"",description:"",content:""},  
  {imgUrl:"",title:"",description:"",content:""},
  ...
]
```

We add a new propertie "isCollapsed" to make the response.articles becomes

```
[
  {imgUrl:"",title:"",description:"",content:"",isCollapsed:true},  
  {imgUrl:"",title:"",description:"",content:"",isCollapsed:false},
  ...
]
```

How we add this "extra" property?

Without modify your .ts work because, as you have an array of object you can add a property directy (in .html as we've made). But you would prefer add this property in .ts. In that case, the only thing you need is

```
//I supouse you have some like
   this.httpClient.get(...).subscribe(response=>{this.response=response})
//replace the line before to transform the response using "map" and spread operator
   this.httpClient.get(...).subscribe(response=>{
        this.response={
           ...response, //all properties of response
                        //but articles we add a property isCollapsed
           articles:response.articles.map(a=>{
               ...a,
               isCollapsed:true
           })
   })
```